# Where to get Ubuntu 18.04.7 LTS

Tags: 18.04, iso, downloads

I'm planning to build Ubuntu Server 18.04.5 LTS on ESXi.
Where can I get the ISO file of Ubuntu 18.04.7 LTS?

I found the following link regarding 22.04.1 LTS, though.
https://jp.ubuntu.com/download

Thank you.

W-P

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 has 5 months of support left. Please install 22.04.

Comment: No 18.04.7 exists; the latest release is [Ubuntu 18.04.6](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/).  Schedules also don't list anything past 18.04.5, it's announced only on ML (mailing lists)

Comment: 18.04.6 is the most current version. You can get from https://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.6/

Comment: Why are you looking for a different version than you plan to install?

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04.7 existed](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-16-04-7-lts-released/) so maybe you're attaching the .7 from *xenial* or 16.04 onto *bionic* or 18.04; but only the first .5 ISO releases are ever scheduled, with later releases only being created/released if required.

Answer (score 4):

Older releases are a bit hidden, but you can find them on the normal [Ubuntu Download site](https://ubuntu.com/download).

- Scroll down to "***Alternative downloads***" and click the link.
- On the next page, you will see "***Past releases and other flavours***" where you will see a link to [Ubuntu 18.04.6](https://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.6/)

Note, the current version is 18.04.6, there is no 18.04.7.
Also, this version will be EOL in 5 month from now, you should go for a newer release!